# Bash Unix: Tee and PID

Tags: unix, pid, tee

**Case 1**

```
RUN_LOG="run.log"
CMD="java -DprofileName=$PROFILE ..."

$CMD &
PID=$!
```

I'm able to run and get the pid.

**Case 2**

```
$CMD | tee $RUN_LOG
```

I'm able to run and log the result to a file..

Do you know how can I join both?
I want to log to the file and console, plus get the pid as an ENV variable.

**Attempt 1:**

```
(echo "Command PID is $BASHPID";exec $CMD;) | tee $RUN_LOG
```

It outputs to the file but the pid is not in a variable in the end.

**Attempt 2:**

```
$CMD & PID=$! >> $RUN_LOG
```

pid is in the ENV variable *PID* but the log file in empty.

Summary, I need to get the pid in a env variable PID, output the execution log from CMD both to console and file ("run.log")

Answer (score 1):

Variables can't escape subshells. Write your pid via file or fifo instead:

```
tmp=$(mktemp -u)
mkfifo "$tmp"
( echo "$BASHPID" > "$tmp"; exec $CMD ) | tee "$RUN_LOG" &
pid=$(cat "$tmp")
rm "$tmp"
```